# Remove Red errors In Visual Studio Code Show Error In Php

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've been encountering an issue in Visual Studio Code where it keeps showing syntax errors in my PHP code. I'm looking for a way to fix or disable this feature, as I suspect the problem might be related to a specific Visual Studio Code extension. However, I'm not entirely sure which extension is causing the issue, and I'd appreciate any guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue effectively

[image]

i don't know what to do

Comment: Did you try disabling the possible extensions, one at a time unil you find the one that is causing this validation

Comment: I would start with Intelephense, but thats just a guess